# Какую библеотеку использовать для работы с картой оффлайн?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Необходимо использовать карту города оффлайн, без подключения к интернету.
Карта должна быть сохранена в памяти телефона.

Карты может быть статичной, не масштабирующей главное условия, чтобы была возможность отрисовать на карте линии перевиденных из **графических координат** типа (`65.249877`, `55.463608`). То есть учитывался масштаб карты.

Как я понял Google не разрешаешь использовать их карты без конекции к интернету.

По этому смотрю в сторону OpenStreetMap. Для данного сервиса нашёл не сколь библиотек описанных в этой [статье](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/susan812/diary/34992)

Мне интересен опыт других людей кто уже пробовал работать в данном направлении.

Что использовать?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Mapbox, насколько я знаю, у них поддерживается кеширование

Answer (score 0):

Привет, я опытный человек в этом направлении. В свое время я делал карты на основе "мп" формата, он же "польский" формат. Это достаточно простой формат для понимания и в него есть конверторы из ОСМ, но его не очень удобно рендерить, как и собственно голый ОСМ тоже (ОСМ на самом деле гораздо сложнее).

Для начала определяешь пару функций: преобразование широты/долготы в экранные пиксели и обратно. Где-то тут можно использовать формулы для различных проекций, к примеру, часто выбирают проекцию Меркатора. Если проекция или задача позволяет, то можно сразу все координаты трансформировать в экранные - так будет быстрее и удобнее работать.

Затем берешь точки из своей карты, преобразовываешь в экранные координаты, и если оно оказалось на экране - рисуешь на канвасе/сцене, что у тебя там есть. Если за экраном - лучше не рисовать. Чтобы работало быстрее - делаешь индекс на основе р-три или квад-три.

Отрисовка линий и полигонов идет по тому же принципу, но здесь есть нюанс: линию и уж тем более полигон надо рисовать даже в том случае, если она выходит за границы экрана. Поэтому разумнее сначала разбить карту на небольшие области, с пересчетом полигонов. Грубо говоря, если у нас есть огромное озеро, то после разбиения оно станет кучей маленьких прямоугольничков с простыми полигонами по краям, которые рендерить можно будет проще и в случае выхода за границы экрана, потери будут минимальны.

Полигоны можно заранее упаковать в фан или снейк-последовательности, что может дать немного преимущества при работе с некоторым железом, но в наше время, я думаю, это не имеет большой роли. Это я в былые времена выковыривал производительность так.

Ну и в общем-то все что надо уже есть. Осталось написать индексатор, который будет раскладывать нарезанные линии и полигоны по разным участкам, какой-то там оптимизатор, чтобы на разных масштабах точки, сливающиеся в единое целое прореживал, ну и бенчмаркать все это пока не надоест. Работа с профайлером продолжается до тех пор, пока не будет более-менее гладких анимаций или это не надоест.

Сверху добавляем надписи (удобнее их хранить отдельным слоем), какие-то иконочки, маркеры и так далее, и если все это рисуем в полноэкранном виде - выше всего рисуем свой гуй. Все, приложение работает, карта есть, ни от кого не зависим.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное описания, способа решения задачи, вы весьма знающий человек. 
Мне бы хотелось от вас услышат мнения по нескольким вопросам.
Почему стоить использовать "польский" формат (пожалуйста дайте ссылку на описания данного формата)
Как я понял мне придётся самому создавать функции преобразования координат? 
Нет ли готовой библиотеки где уже решины данные задачи? 
Чем плох OSM формат? 
Я ковыряю на данный момент эту [библеотеку](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki). Вы можете что-то прокомментировать по этому?

Comment: Польский формат лучше не использовать, он просто уже был и он прост для понимания. Описание легко ищется в гугле. Функции преобразования можно найти в википедии, а готовый код стырить из любой библиотеки, работающей с проекциями. Можно вообще сразу все координаты в Меркатор засунуть и представить, что работаешь с пикселями и просто очень большой картинкой - полная свобода. Библиотек готовых для решения море, но я не макака, которой надо срочно сдавать проект, а программист и предпочитаю решать задачи сам, отвечая за. ОСМ формат просто великолепен, но рендерить его сложно, попробуете - узнаете.

Comment: Извините за назойливость, вы могли бы уточнить, что вы понимаете под "ОСМ - рендерить его сложнее"?

Comment: Конечно уточню. Если тебе надо нарисовать дорогу или домик, то просто берем данные полилинии или полигона и рендерим линию или полигончик. Все. В ОСМ немного не так. Во-первых, есть множество форматов, в которых представлены его данные, как бинарные, так и текстовые, вроде XML. Во-вторых, если мы найдем данные дороги, то вместо координат с широтой/долготой, мы получим лишь список идентификаторов, которые должны будем найти потом отдельно, чтобы узнать эти координаты. Если мы хотим отрендерить полигоны - нам надо найти все отношения. В целом, это более правильно, но вот рендерить сложнее.